# how to replace the NA in a data frame with the average number of this data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
nums  id
1233 1     
3232 2    
2334 3     
3330 1    
1445 3     
3455 3     
7632 2
NA   3
NA   1
```

And I can know the average "nums" of each "id" by using:

```
id_avg <- aggregate(nums ~ id, data = dat, FUN = mean)
```

What I would like to do is to replace the NA with the value of the average number of the corresponding id. for example, the average "nums" of 1,2,3 are 1000, 2000, 3000, respectively. The NA when id == 3 will be replaced by 3000, the last NA whose id == 1 will be replaced by 1000.
I tried the following code to achieve this:

```
temp <- dat[is.na(dat$nums),]$id
dat[is.na(dat$nums),]$nums <- id_avg[id_avg[,"id"] ==temp,]$nums
```

However, the second part

```
id_avg[id_avg[,"id"] ==temp,]$nums
```

is always NA, which means I always pass NA to the NAs I want to replace.
I don't know where I was wrong, or do you have better method to do this?
Thank you

Comment: @ Zheyuan Li I added the na.rm = TRUE, however, the same problem

Comment: Statistically this is a very dangerous method of imputing values. Any attempt at drawing conclusions about strength of associations will be thrown off by this strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` way:

```
df %>% 
       group_by(id) %>% 
       mutate(nums = replace(nums, is.na(nums), as.integer(mean(nums, na.rm = T))))

# Source: local data frame [9 x 2]
# Groups: id [3]

#    nums    id
#   <int> <int>
# 1  1233     1
# 2  3232     2
# 3  2334     3
# 4  3330     1
# 5  1445     3
# 6  3455     3
# 7  7632     2
# 8  2411     3
# 9  2281     1
```

You essentially want to merge the `id_avg` back to the original data frame by the `id` column, so you can also use `match` to follow your original logic:

```
dat$nums[is.na(dat$nums)] <- id_avg$nums[match(dat$id[is.na(dat$nums)], id_avg$id)]
dat
#        nums id
# 1: 1233.000  1
# 2: 3232.000  2
# 3: 2334.000  3
# 4: 3330.000  1
# 5: 1445.000  3
# 6: 3455.000  3
# 7: 7632.000  2
# 8: 2411.333  3
# 9: 2281.500  1
```

Comment: Or in one long ugly `ave` line following the same logic - `dat$nums[is.na(dat$nums)] <- with(dat, ave(nums, id, FUN=function(x) mean(x,na.rm=TRUE) ) )[is.na(dat$nums)]`

Comment: How come you have `as.integer` in the `mutate` statement? You lose accuracy that way. (And no, I didn't downvote)

Comment: @thelatemail Just tried to keep the original column type. It might be better to have a numeric column if the accuracy is important. In reality, I would not use `as.integer`. :)

Answer (score 4):

Or you can fix it by:

```
dat[is.na(dat$nums),]$nums <- id_avg$nums[temp]

      nums id
1 1233.000  1
2 3232.000  2
3 2334.000  3
4 3330.000  1
5 1445.000  3
6 3455.000  3
7 7632.000  2
8 2411.333  3
9 2281.500  1
```

Answer (score 3):

What you want is contained in the `zoo` package.

```
library(zoo)
na.aggregate.default(dat, by = dat$id)

      nums id
1 1233.000  1
2 3232.000  2
3 2334.000  3
4 3330.000  1
5 1445.000  3
6 3455.000  3
7 7632.000  2
8 2411.333  3
9 2281.500  1
```